# Directory splitting

Tags: windows, batch-file

There is a directory which needs to be split into two i.e relocate certain files and sub-directories to a new directory.

There are two lists: A-> The list of files and sub-directories to be retained in the original Directory.

B-> The list of files and sub-directories to be relocated to a new directory.

Before doing the relocation, i want to verify that these two lists together contain all the files and sub-directories in the original directory.

I'm not able to figure out the logic to write this verification script.

Can someone please suggest how i can go about this?

Comment: Did you try to write those lists into a file, sort it with `sort` and compare (`fc`) with sorted file list (`dir /b /o:n`) for that directory? they have to match.

Comment: In essence it is easy - but it depends what is in your files.  `d:\folder\file.ext` on every line?

Comment: the problem is my list DOESN't have d:\folder\file.ext on every line. There are folders also listed which would be relocated. I want to verify that all the folders and files are present.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list files contain the names of the files (as they are in the same folder there is no need for the path), this command

```
dir /b | findstr /l /v /x /i /g:list1 | findstr /l /v /x /i /g:list2
```

should return the list of files that are not contained in none of the two lists.

What it does is enumerate all the files, filter the list searching the elements not in list1 and then this list is filtered for the elements not in list2.

Comment: I've a problem. Suppose there is M:\Folder1\Folder2\somefile.txt in list1, it would be matched with M:\Folder1\Folder2\somefile.txt in the output of dir /b /s But either of my list don't have an entry for M:\Folder1\ but it will be present in the output of dir /b /s. How can i remove such entries?

Comment: @user3437212, The code in the answer does not use any `/s` as the  question asks about the contents of *one* folder (files and folders inside them) that needs to be split. Under this scenario, there is no need for a recursive search nor for a full path inside the lists. If this is not the real case, please, update your question with the real requirements and a sample of the content of the two files.